# c++ two errors while compiling

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a beginner in c++ and I'm getting two errors in my code and I don't know how to fix them...
the first one

> illegal indirection

and the second one is

> '=' left operand must be a I-value. (in the line: *(*(ArrayPtr +i)+j)=rand()%55+1 )

Does anyone have an idea how to fix them? That's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<array>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int AS = 6;
void FillingRandomly(int (*)[AS]);
void printing(int (*)[AS]);
int c;
int main()
{
    int funny = 0;
    int timpa = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int Array[AS][AS];
    srand(time(0));
    FillingRandomly(Array);
    cout << "The unsorted array is" << endl << endl;
    printing(Array);
    cout << "The sorted array is" << endl << endl;
    printing(Array);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void FillingRandomly(int *ArrayPtr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<AS;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<AS;j++)
        {
            *(*(ArrayPtr +i)+j)=rand()%55+1;
        }
    }
}
void printing(int *Array)
{
    for(int i=0;i<AS;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<AS*AS;j++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            cout<<((Array[i] +j))<<setw(5);
            if ((Array[i] +j)%AS == 0)
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
void forsorting(int *Brray, int funny)
{
    int dice = 0;
    int super = 0;
    int space=0;
    //Sorting Array[][] which is treated like Array[]
    {
        for (int pass = 0; pass < AS - 1; pass++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < AS - 1; k++) {
                int temp;
                if(*(Brray+k)==*(Brray+k+1))
                {
                    temp=*(Brray+k);
                    *(Brray+k)=*(Brray+k+1);
                    *(Brray+k+1)=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "((ArrayPtr +i)+j)=rand()%55+1 )" if you're a beginner, why do you write code like a hacker? Split that into several lines, each doing one thing at a time. This will help you locate your errors and maybe even prevent some of them. Also, dropping your whole code here and asking us to fix it is not a good idea. Please be more specific and ask only one about one problem.

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier to read.

Comment: And tell us which line is generating the problem.

Answer (score 3):

By

```
*(*(ArrayPtr +i)+j)=rand()%55+1;
```

it seems you want

```
ArrayPtr[i][j] = (rand() % 55) + 1;
```

You can try something along the line of

```
int const offset = AS * i + j;
int const elem = (rand() % 55) + 1;
*(ArrayPtr + offset) = elem;
```

Comment: thank you for answering... I did what you told me but i got another two errors... (error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl FillingRandomly(int (*)[6])" (?FillingRandomly@@YAXPAY05H@Z) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl printing(int (*)[6])" (?printing@@YAXPAY05H@Z) referenced in function _main ) what do you think?

Comment: That is new/different error. Most probably you have to change the declaration of FillingRandomly() to `void FillingRandomly(int *);` You might have to do the same change for printing() declaration.

Comment: i changed them and i also got another error lol ( FillingRandomly() , printing() cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int[6][6]' to 'int*'

Comment: Can you please update with your latest code? As I mentioned, you might need to change the signature of printing() similarly to `void printing(int *);`

Answer (score 2):

Your function signature is:

```
void FillingRandomly(int *ArrayPtr)
```

where you are telling to compiler that you are passing a simple pointer, but in the line:

```
*(*(ArrayPtr +i)+j)=rand()%55+1;
```

you are doing a double derreference, which is illegal and causing the compiler to complain

**COMPLEMENT**

I was seeing the comments in the other answer and, as what I need to write is bigger than the reserved commentary space, I decided to complement my own answer.

You defined `Array` as:

int Array[AS][AS];

Indeed, what you are doing is a promise to compiler that you will use Array as defined, but the compiler doesn't believe in you too much, so that any time you use `Array` the compiler will make sure that it is being used as declared.

The problem arises when you declare your `FillingRandomly` function. Here you are broking your promise and are trying to use `Array` by declaring a differente type. Note how you declare your function:

```
void FillingRandomly(int *ArrayPtr)
```

Due the fact that c++ supports function overloading, the compiler doesn't warn you until it initiate the linking phase, when it is unable to find a function whose signature is:

```
void FillingRandomly(int ArrayPtr[][AS])
```

note that both are different.

Once you are a beginner, the best way to keep your programs correctly is to keep your promise immutable. Bellow I show you a piece of your own code, correcting those issues for `FillingRandomly` function (you have to correct it for the others functions too):

```
const int AS = 6;
void FillingRandomly(int [][AS]); // Note that I've changed your prototype here
....

void FillingRandomly(int ArrayPtr[][AS]) // Keep your function signature the same as your prototype signature
{
    for(int i=0;i<AS;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<AS;j++)
        {
            ArrayPtr[i][j]=rand()%55+1;  // Note how ArrayPtr is being used exactly as your promised early
        }
    }
}
```